# Feedback box in my android app

Tags: java, android, feedback

I am working on my own android app on Android studio, but I have some issues. I create one page that has on the top restaurant information. I want to create small box down on the page that allow guests to to evaluate the restaurant then add comment and that comment appear on small box.

Could you please help me with that? Or give me any helpful tutorial? 
I am working in Android studio 2.3.3.

Comment: Share your xml file or your requirement that how exactly you want ?

Comment: Show what you tried. Asking for tutorials is off topic so you better drop that part of your question.